# Automated Daily SMS service(Data from Internet) - Android phone

Tags: android

Quite simply, I'm looking to make a daily SMS service. More specifically: Once every day -> Connect to the Internet -> Get the text to be sent out + Recipients -> Send(Perhaps scheduled) -> Connect to the Internet with success/failure info.

A windows SMS gateway solution is simply too expensive as other than the SMS gateway license you have to have a computer running all day, licenses and so on.

I have a couple of questions regarding this:

- 1) Is it possible to have a app
  connect to the web and get the data
  needed without user interaction
  perhaps with some notification(If the
  user cancels, fine, if not it goes
  ahead)?
- 2) Is it possible to send SMS's
  without user interaction?

Would just like to know if it's possible with the current API before I start for real on trying this out.

The reason for the andriod app is that it can then be used in a number of countries, where they all just get the data needed from my website database/txt file and send to their local country.